# Trying to make a text-inputted game, but there are problems in the code

Tags: python

I make this code about hand cricket in IDLE, which has 2 innings of play between computer and the player. The "runs" (points) made in the first innings/half need to be crossed by the other side.

When I use the variable runs, which should have the number of runs scored by the user, I get this error
`runs1= runs NameError: name 'runs' is not defined. Did you mean: 'round'?`

My code was:

```
import random
import time
print("Welcome to Hand Cricket!")
toss= input("Heads or Tails?")
cointoss = ["heads", "tails"]
inning = ["bat", "ball"]
coin= random.choice(cointoss)
Toss= toss.lower()
 
if Toss.strip() not in cointoss:
    while Toss.strip() not in cointoss:
        print("Input a valid choice")
        toss= input('Heads or Tails?')
        Toss= toss.lower()

if Toss.lower()== coin.lower():
    choice= input('You have won the toss! Do you choose to bat or ball')
    Choice= choice.lower()
    while Choice.strip() not in inning:
        print("Input a valid choice")
        choice= input('Do you choose to bat or bowl')
        Choice= choice.lower()
else:
    print("You have lost the toss :( Computer is choosing")
    time.sleep(2)
    choice= random.choice(inning)
    Choice= choice.lower()
    print("Well then, computer has chosen to",Choice,"first!")


def batinning1():
    print("First Innings Starts now! Start Batting!")
    runs= 0
    for i in range(1,121):
        bat1= int(input("Enter number of runs you want to take"))
        if bat1 not in range(0,7):
            while bat1 not in range(0,7):
                print("What is that shot? Enter between 0 and 6")
                bat1= int(input("Enter number of runs you want to take"))
        bowl1= random.randint(0, 6)
        time.sleep(2)
        if bat1==bowl1:
            print("HOWZAAT!!! You are out!")
            print("Computer chose", bowl1)
            break
        else:
            runs+= bat1
            if bat1==0:
                print("Batsman Defended that one quite well!") #Can add option using random.choice(list) for more commentary
            elif bat1==1:
                print("Batsman takes a quick single")
            elif bat1==2:
                print("Batsman tries to hit the ball, and takes quick double")
            elif bat1==3:
                print("Batsman has taken a rare triple")
            elif bat1==4:
                print("ITS A FOUUURRRRR!!! Batsman has hit that one for a boundary!")
            elif bat1==5:
                print("An overthrow by the fielders, and its a boundary, meaning 5 runs!")
            elif bat1==6:
                print("ITS A SIX! WHAT A SHOT BY THE BATSMAN!")
    print("You have scored", runs ,"runs! Now you have to defend", runs+1,"runs")

    
def bowlinning1():
    print("First Innings Starts now! Start Bowling!")
    runs= 0
    for i in range(1,121):
        bowl1= int(input("What do you think the computer will score?"))
        if bowl1 not in range(0,7):
            while bowl1 not in range(0,7):
                print("What is that shot? Enter between 0 and 6")
                bowl1 = int(input("What do you think the computer will score?"))
        bat1= random.randint(0, 6)
        time.sleep(2)
        if bat1==bowl1:
            print("HOWZAAT!!! ITS A WICKET!")
            break
        else:
            runs+= bat1
            if bat1==0:
                print("Batsman Defended that one quite well!") #Can add option using random.choice(list) for more commentary
            elif bat1==1:
                print("Batsman takes a quick single")
            elif bat1==2:
                print("Batsman tries to hit the ball, and takes quick double")
            elif bat1==3:
                print("Batsman has taken a rare triple")
            elif bat1==4:
                print("ITS A FOUUURRRRR!!! Batsman has hit that one for a boundary!")
            elif bat1==5:
                print("An overthrow by the fielders, and its a boundary, meaning 5 runs!")
            elif bat1==6:
                print("ITS A SIX! WHAT A SHOT BY THE BATSMAN!")
    print("Computer has scored", runs,"runs! You now need to score", runs+1,"runs to win!")

def batinning2():
    print("Second Innings Starts now! Start Batting!")
    runs2= 0
    for i in range(1,121):
        bat1= int(input("Enter number of runs you want to take"))
        if bat1 not in range(0,7):
            while bat1 not in range(0,7):
                print("What is that shot? Enter between 0 and 6")
                bat1= int(input("Enter number of runs you want to take"))
        bowl1= random.randint(0, 6)
        time.sleep(2)
        while runs2<runs+1:
            if bat1==bowl1:
                print("HOWZAAT!!! You are out! You lose this math :(")
                print("Computer chose", bowl1)
                break
            else:
                runs+= bat1
                if bat1==0:
                    print("Batsman Defended that one quite well!") #Can add option using random.choice(list) for more commentary
                elif bat1==1:
                    print("Batsman takes a quick single")
                elif bat1==2:
                    print("Batsman tries to hit the ball, and takes quick double")
                elif bat1==3:
                    print("Batsman has taken a rare triple")
                elif bat1==4:
                    print("ITS A FOUUURRRRR!!! Batsman has hit that one for a boundary!")
                elif bat1==5:
                    print("An overthrow by the fielders, and its a boundary, meaning 5 runs!")
                elif bat1==6:
                    print("ITS A SIX! WHAT A SHOT BY THE BATSMAN!")
    if runs2>=runs+1:
        print("AND THE BATSMAN FINISHES IN STYLE! ITS A WIN FOR YOU!!!")

def bowlinning2():
    print("Second Innings Starts now! Start Bowling!")
    runs2= 0
    while runs2>runs+1:
        for i in range(1,121):
            bowl1= int(input("Enter number of runs you want to take"))
            if bowl1 not in range(0,7):
                while bowl1 not in range(0,7):
                    print("What is that shot? Enter between 0 and 6")
                    bowl1 = int(input("What do you think the computer will score?"))
            bat1= random.randint(0, 6)
            time.sleep(2)
            if bat1==bowl1:
                print("HOWZAAT!!! ITS A WICKET! YOU WIN THIS MATCH BY", runs-runs2)
                break
            else:
                runs+= bat1
                if bat1==0:
                    print("Batsman Defended that one quite well!") #Can add option using random.choice(list) for more commentary
                elif bat1==1:
                    print("Batsman takes a quick single")
                elif bat1==2:
                    print("Batsman tries to hit the ball, and takes quick double")
                elif bat1==3:
                    print("Batsman has taken a rare triple")
                elif bat1==4:
                    print("ITS A FOUUURRRRR!!! Batsman has hit that one for a boundary!")
                elif bat1==5:
                    print("An overthrow by the fielders, and its a boundary, meaning 5 runs!")
                elif bat1==6:
                    print("ITS A SIX! WHAT A SHOT BY THE BATSMAN!")
    if runs2>=runs+1:
        print("AND THE BATSMAN FINISHES IN STYLE! Its a loss for you ")
        
if Toss.lower()== coin.lower():
    if Choice == 'bat':
        batinning1()
    elif Choice== 'ball':
        bowlinning1()
else:
    if Choice == 'bat':
        bowlinning1()
    elif Choice== 'ball':
        batinning1()

time.sleep(2)
        
if Toss.lower()== coin.lower():
    if choice.lower() == 'bat':
        bowlinning2()
    elif choice.lower()== 'ball':
        batinning2()
else:
    if choice.lower() == 'bat':
        batinning2()
    elif choice.lower()== 'ball':
        bowlinning2()
```

Comment: The `runs` variable is local to `bowlinning1`.  When that function ends, the variable goes away.  What you really need is ONE function, not four virtually identical functions.  You can pass in a dictionary or object with the current "state" of that team, and have the function update the state, or return the new state.  That way, it's trivial to go from 2 innings to 8 or whatever  Don't Repeat Yourself.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using global variables in a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/423379/using-global-variables-in-a-function)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here, take a look at this.  I'm not actually sure I have implemented your rules, but this shows how you have use the same function for all the purposes you need.  Note how I put the "bat" and "bowl" function in an array and call them alternately.

```
import random
import time
print("Welcome to Hand Cricket!")

toss= input("Heads or Tails?")
cointoss = ["heads", "tails"]
toss= toss.lower().strip()
 
while toss not in cointoss:
    print("Input a valid choice")
    toss = input('Heads or Tails?')
    toss = toss.lower()

side = ["bat", "ball"]
coin = random.choice(cointoss)

if toss == coin:
    choice= input('You have won the toss! Do you choose to bat or ball').lower().strip()
    while choice not in side:
        print("Input a valid choice")
        choice= input('Do you choose to bat or ball').lower().strip()

else:
    print("You have lost the toss :( Computer is choosing")
    choice= random.choice(side)
    print("Well then, computer has chosen to",choice,"first!")

innings = ['First','Second','Third']

def batinning(inning,player):
    runs = player['runs']
    print(innings[inning],"Innings Starts now! Start Batting!")
    for i in range(1,121):
        bat = int(input("Enter number of runs you want to take"))
        while bat not in range(0,7):
            print("What is that shot? Enter between 0 and 6")
            bat = int(input("Enter number of runs you want to take"))
        bowl= random.randint(0, 6)
#        time.sleep(2)
        if bat==bowl:
            print("HOWZAAT!!! You are out!")
            print("Computer chose", bowl)
            break
        else:
            runs += bat
            if bat==0:
                print("Batsman Defended that one quite well!") #Can add option using random.choice(list) for more commentary
            elif bat==1:
                print("Batsman takes a quick single")
            elif bat==2:
                print("Batsman tries to hit the ball, and takes quick double")
            elif bat==3:
                print("Batsman has taken a rare triple")
            elif bat==4:
                print("ITS A FOUUURRRRR!!! Batsman has hit that one for a boundary!")
            elif bat==5:
                print("An overthrow by the fielders, and its a boundary, meaning 5 runs!")
            elif bat==6:
                print("ITS A SIX! WHAT A SHOT BY THE BATSMAN!")
    print("You have scored", runs ,"runs! Now you have to defend", runs+1,"runs")
    player['runs'] = runs

    
def bowlinning(inning,player):
    print(innings[inning],"Innings Starts now! Start Bowling!")
    runs = player['runs']
    for i in range(1,121):
        bowl1= int(input("What do you think the computer will score?"))
        while bowl1 not in range(0,7):
            print("What is that shot? Enter between 0 and 6")
            bowl1 = int(input("What do you think the computer will score?"))
        bat1= random.randint(0, 6)
#        time.sleep(2)
        if bat1==bowl1:
            print("HOWZAAT!!! ITS A WICKET!")
            break
        else:
            runs += bat1
            if bat1==0:
                print("Batsman Defended that one quite well!") #Can add option using random.choice(list) for more commentary
            elif bat1==1:
                print("Batsman takes a quick single")
            elif bat1==2:
                print("Batsman tries to hit the ball, and takes quick double")
            elif bat1==3:
                print("Batsman has taken a rare triple")
            elif bat1==4:
                print("ITS A FOUUURRRRR!!! Batsman has hit that one for a boundary!")
            elif bat1==5:
                print("An overthrow by the fielders, and its a boundary, meaning 5 runs!")
            elif bat1==6:
                print("ITS A SIX! WHAT A SHOT BY THE BATSMAN!")
    print("Computer has scored", runs,"runs! You now need to score", runs+1,"runs to win!")
    player['runs'] = runs


user = {'runs': 0}
computer = {'runs':0}

order = [batinning,bowlinning]
if toss == coin and choice == 'ball':
    order.reverse()
if toss != coin and choice == 'bat':
    order.reverse()

for inning,player in ((0,user),(1,computer)):
    order[inning % 2]( inning, player )

if user['runs'] > computer['runs']:
    print("AND THE BATSMAN FINISHES IN STYLE! ITS A WIN FOR YOU!!!")
elif user['runs'] < computer['runs']:
    print("AND THE BATSMAN FINISHES IN STYLE! Its a loss for you!!!")
else:
    print("How can that be?  It's a tie!")
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, I think I know what is happening. It also happened to me.
Look do you know what global variables are?
Well you should make it global like this

```
def batinning1():
    
    global runs

    #rest of the code
```

Remember to put that in the start of every function in which you use it and put

```
runs = 0
```

in case you need it for the global part.

This may be strange for most people because actually this is not very necessary but for a strange reason sometimes work. In my case, it has happened more than one time.
For more info about global and local variables check out this link: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/global-local-variables-python/

Hope it works!!

This is the complete code if you want it:

```
import random
import time
print("Welcome to Hand Cricket!")
toss = input("Heads or Tails?")
cointoss = ["heads", "tails"]
inning = ["bat", "ball"]
coin = random.choice(cointoss)
Toss = toss.lower()

runs = 0
 
if Toss.strip() not in cointoss:
    while Toss.strip() not in cointoss:
        print("Input a valid choice")
        toss = input('Heads or Tails?')
        Toss = toss.lower()

if Toss.lower() == coin.lower():
    choice = input('You have won the toss! Do you choose to bat or ball')
    Choice = choice.lower()
    while Choice.strip() not in inning:
        print("Input a valid choice")
        choice = input('Do you choose to bat or bowl')
        Choice = choice.lower()
else:
    print("You have lost the toss :( Computer is choosing")
    time.sleep(2)
    choice = random.choice(inning)
    Choice = choice.lower()
    print("Well then, computer has chosen to",Choice,"first!")


def batinning1():
    
    global runs
    
    print("First Innings Starts now! Start Batting!")
    runs = 0
    for i in range(1,121):
        bat1 = int(input("Enter number of runs you want to take"))
        if bat1 not in range(0,7):
            while bat1 not in range(0,7):
                print("What is that shot? Enter between 0 and 6")
                bat1= int(input("Enter number of runs you want to take"))
        bowl1= random.randint(0, 6)
        time.sleep(2)
        if bat1==bowl1:
            print("HOWZAAT!!! You are out!")
            print("Computer chose", bowl1)
            break
        else:
            runs+= bat1
            if bat1==0:
                print("Batsman Defended that one quite well!") #Can add option using random.choice(list) for more commentary
            elif bat1==1:
                print("Batsman takes a quick single")
            elif bat1==2:
                print("Batsman tries to hit the ball, and takes quick double")
            elif bat1==3:
                print("Batsman has taken a rare triple")
            elif bat1==4:
                print("ITS A FOUUURRRRR!!! Batsman has hit that one for a boundary!")
            elif bat1==5:
                print("An overthrow by the fielders, and its a boundary, meaning 5 runs!")
            elif bat1==6:
                print("ITS A SIX! WHAT A SHOT BY THE BATSMAN!")
    print("You have scored", runs ,"runs! Now you have to defend", runs+1,"runs")

    
def bowlinning1():
    
    global runs
    
    print("First Innings Starts now! Start Bowling!")
    runs= 0
    for i in range(1,121):
        bowl1= int(input("What do you think the computer will score?"))
        if bowl1 not in range(0,7):
            while bowl1 not in range(0,7):
                print("What is that shot? Enter between 0 and 6")
                bowl1 = int(input("What do you think the computer will score?"))
        bat1= random.randint(0, 6)
        time.sleep(2)
        if bat1==bowl1:
            print("HOWZAAT!!! ITS A WICKET!")
            break
        else:
            runs+= bat1
            if bat1==0:
                print("Batsman Defended that one quite well!") #Can add option using random.choice(list) for more commentary
            elif bat1==1:
                print("Batsman takes a quick single")
            elif bat1==2:
                print("Batsman tries to hit the ball, and takes quick double")
            elif bat1==3:
                print("Batsman has taken a rare triple")
            elif bat1==4:
                print("ITS A FOUUURRRRR!!! Batsman has hit that one for a boundary!")
            elif bat1==5:
                print("An overthrow by the fielders, and its a boundary, meaning 5 runs!")
            elif bat1==6:
                print("ITS A SIX! WHAT A SHOT BY THE BATSMAN!")
    print("Computer has scored", runs,"runs! You now need to score", runs+1,"runs to win!")

def batinning2():
    
    global runs
    
    print("Second Innings Starts now! Start Batting!")
    runs2= 0
    for i in range(1,121):
        bat1= int(input("Enter number of runs you want to take"))
        if bat1 not in range(0,7):
            while bat1 not in range(0,7):
                print("What is that shot? Enter between 0 and 6")
                bat1= int(input("Enter number of runs you want to take"))
        bowl1= random.randint(0, 6)
        time.sleep(2)
        while runs2<runs+1:
            if bat1==bowl1:
                print("HOWZAAT!!! You are out! You lose this math :(")
                print("Computer chose", bowl1)
                break
            else:
                runs+= bat1
                if bat1==0:
                    print("Batsman Defended that one quite well!") #Can add option using random.choice(list) for more commentary
                elif bat1==1:
                    print("Batsman takes a quick single")
                elif bat1==2:
                    print("Batsman tries to hit the ball, and takes quick double")
                elif bat1==3:
                    print("Batsman has taken a rare triple")
                elif bat1==4:
                    print("ITS A FOUUURRRRR!!! Batsman has hit that one for a boundary!")
                elif bat1==5:
                    print("An overthrow by the fielders, and its a boundary, meaning 5 runs!")
                elif bat1==6:
                    print("ITS A SIX! WHAT A SHOT BY THE BATSMAN!")
    if runs2>=runs+1:
        print("AND THE BATSMAN FINISHES IN STYLE! ITS A WIN FOR YOU!!!")

def bowlinning2():
    
    global runs
    
    print("Second Innings Starts now! Start Bowling!")
    runs2= 0
    while runs2>runs+1:
        for i in range(1,121):
            bowl1= int(input("Enter number of runs you want to take"))
            if bowl1 not in range(0,7):
                while bowl1 not in range(0,7):
                    print("What is that shot? Enter between 0 and 6")
                    bowl1 = int(input("What do you think the computer will score?"))
            bat1= random.randint(0, 6)
            time.sleep(2)
            if bat1==bowl1:
                print("HOWZAAT!!! ITS A WICKET! YOU WIN THIS MATCH BY", runs-runs2)
                break
            else:
                runs+= bat1
                if bat1==0:
                    print("Batsman Defended that one quite well!") #Can add option using random.choice(list) for more commentary
                elif bat1==1:
                    print("Batsman takes a quick single")
                elif bat1==2:
                    print("Batsman tries to hit the ball, and takes quick double")
                elif bat1==3:
                    print("Batsman has taken a rare triple")
                elif bat1==4:
                    print("ITS A FOUUURRRRR!!! Batsman has hit that one for a boundary!")
                elif bat1==5:
                    print("An overthrow by the fielders, and its a boundary, meaning 5 runs!")
                elif bat1==6:
                    print("ITS A SIX! WHAT A SHOT BY THE BATSMAN!")
    if runs2>=runs+1:
        print("AND THE BATSMAN FINISHES IN STYLE! Its a loss for you ")
        
if Toss.lower()== coin.lower():
    if Choice == 'bat':
        batinning1()
    elif Choice== 'ball':
        bowlinning1()
else:
    if Choice == 'bat':
        bowlinning1()
    elif Choice== 'ball':
        batinning1()

time.sleep(2)
        
if Toss.lower()== coin.lower():
    if choice.lower() == 'bat':
        bowlinning2()
    elif choice.lower()== 'ball':
        batinning2()
else:
    if choice.lower() == 'bat':
        batinning2()
    elif choice.lower()== 'ball':
        bowlinning2()
```

It works.

Comment: THIS IS FOR THE OTHER ANSWER
Sorry for answering here but I can´t comment (reputation things), the thing is, that it gave to me a strange result, It says I win when I lost